# Ordering custom fields in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a `User` model with the following fields:

```py
#models.py
class User(models.Model):
  ...
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, default="")
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  ...
```

I have written a custom field like bellow that can be ordered with `first_name`, `middle_name` and `last_name`:

```py
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    list_display = ("username", "email", "full_name", "is_staff", "date_joined")
    list_filter = ("is_staff", "is_active")

    @admin.display(ordering=("first_name", "middle_name", "last_name"))
    def full_name(self, user: User):
        return f"{user.first_name} {user.middle_name} {user.last_name}"
```

But `admin.display(ordering=...)` doesn't work with multiple fields like above.

How to make this custom field ordered by multiple fields?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but I just worked out how to do this. You can use the `OrderBy` and `RawSQL` expressions to list multiple columns. For example:

```py
from django.db.models.expressions import OrderBy, RawSQL

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # ...

    @admin.display(ordering=OrderBy(
        RawSQL("first_name, middle_name, last_name", tuple())
    ))
    def full_name(self, user: User):
        return f"{user.first_name} {user.middle_name} {user.last_name}"
```

But to avoid ambiguity it's probably best to specify the table name too, e.g.:

```py
    @admin.display(ordering=OrderBy(
        RawSQL(
            "users_user.first_name, users_user.middle_name, users_user.last_name",
            tuple()
        )
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all this question might be outdated for you and you probably found a solution, but nonetheless it might be useful for someone else.

Since this will not be saved in the database, the best solution would be to make an annotated field, by which we will later order.

```
from django.db.models import F

list_display=("get_full_name", )

def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(full_name=Case(F("first_name") + F("middle_name") + F("last_name")))
    return qs

@admin.display(ordering="full_name", description="Full name of users")
def get_full_name(self, obj) -> str:
    return obj.full_name
```